Can exit node administrators/ owners get in legal trouble for spying on my traffic?
So if I am using an unencrypted protocol such as HTTP, and don’t self encrypt either- am I right to think that exit node administrators/ owners can actually spy on my traffic?
I am pretty sure that this is true.
So assuming that my exit node owner can- and has been spying on my Tor traffic- can they even get in trouble?
Seeing as Tor is somewhat shunned upon, and in many places illegal, and node owners are just volunteers- could they get into legal trouble?
Obviously this also depends on the country and if Tor is legal in that country; I’m sure there are many other factors influencing this answer.
I’ll also add that I do use Tor, but am advanced and resourceful enough to encrypt my traffic, and not rely on people being good.
I would never recommend using a method that leaves your Tor network traffic open and in the clear for anyone intercepting it.
This might be considered more or a legal question, but you peeps are professionals, so I assumed you might know.
Thanks.

No, because they don't have any obligation to ensure your security. They are not hacking a thing when they are looking at any unencrypted content just by looking at it. You're absolutely right to encrypt your traffic yourself - it's solemnly up to you and nobody else in this world to secure you. Tor is legal everywhere, as to my knowledge - because Tor is just a routing protocol. The thing that is illegal is like a drug sold - but it's totally unrelated to Tor

No, They can't get into any sort of legal trouble only because they can see your data via an exit node they made. They have not signed anything that ensures that they have to maintain your security or privacy.
You should take secure measures and never send any critical data without encrypting it yourself.
